# dplyr filter function in combination with agrep

Tags: r, dplyr, agrep

I'm trying to filter only rows from my table that have the word "dog" in the title column but I cannot get it to work.

Here's a data example:

```
    ID NozamaItemID                                                    NozamaTitle 
1 4557  12000017544 Starbucks Double Shot Espresso Light (4 Count, 6.5 Fl Oz Each) 
2 4558  12000021992                                        Pepsi, 8Ct, 12Oz Bottle 
3 4559  12000024542                     Zuke'S Natural Hip Action dog Treats, 3 Oz 
4 4560  12000030680                  Pepsi Made With Real Sugar, 12 Ct, 12 Oz Cans 
5 4561  12000030680                  Pepsi Made With Real Sugar, 12 Ct, 12 Oz Cans 
6 4562  12000030680                  Pepsi Made With Real Sugar, 12 Ct, 12 Oz Cans
```

The following code should work but does not:

```
amzp <- select(amz, ID, NozamaItemID, NozamaTitle, NozamaCustomerID)

searchTerm="cat|dog"
amzp.a <- mutate(amzp, animalFood = ifelse(grepl(searchTerm, amzp$NozamaTitle, ignore.case = TRUE) == TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))
```

I would expect to see a TRUE for row 3. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @DrikLX please refrain from adding code snippets when they don't work

Comment: Furthermore: you are much more likely to get a good answer when you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: @jaap, I don't agree with your first comment - if they didn't provide any code people would ask them 'what have you tried?' and it will be a better learning for them if people can tell them why their approach failed imo.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Reading my comment again, I see that I expressed myself poorly. I agree that code needs to be included. But I disagree about including blue "run code snippet" buttons which do nothing more that just give the code which was already mentioned above the button. They are just a distraction in this case

Comment: @jaap, in that case I do agree with you.

Comment: Your original code contains several components which are not needed (the `ifelse`-statement and using `data$column` inside a standard dplyr function), it does work. Using `amzp.a <- mutate(amzp, animalFood = grepl(searchTerm, NozamaTitle, ignore.case = TRUE))` gives you the same result. Voting to close as no longer reproducible.

Comment: Sorry. Next time I'll do better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, you just need to get rid off the `ifelse`:

```
amzp.a <- mutate(amzp, animalFood = grepl(searchTerm, 
                         NozamaTitle, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

which gives:

```
> amzp.a
    ID NozamaItemID                                                     NozamaTitle animalFood
1 4557  12000017544  Starbucks Double Shot Espresso Light (4 Count, 6.5 Fl Oz Each)      FALSE
2 4558  12000021992                                         Pepsi, 8Ct, 12Oz Bottle      FALSE
3 4559  12000024542                      Zuke'S Natural Hip Action dog Treats, 3 Oz       TRUE
4 4560  12000030680                   Pepsi Made With Real Sugar, 12 Ct, 12 Oz Cans      FALSE
5 4561  12000030680                   Pepsi Made With Real Sugar, 12 Ct, 12 Oz Cans      FALSE
6 4562  12000030680                   Pepsi Made With Real Sugar, 12 Ct, 12 Oz Cans      FALSE
```

---

Used data:

```
amzp <- structure(list(ID = 4557:4562,
                       NozamaItemID = c(12000017544, 12000021992, 12000024542, 12000030680, 12000030680, 12000030680),
                       NozamaTitle = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Pepsi, 8Ct, 12Oz Bottle","Zuke'S Natural Hip Action dog Treats, 3 Oz","Pepsi Made With Real Sugar, 12 Ct, 12 Oz Cans","Starbucks Double Shot Espresso Light (4 Count, 6.5 Fl Oz Each)"), class = "factor")),
                  .Names = c("ID", "NozamaItemID", "NozamaTitle"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

---

EDIT: Your original code:

```
amzp.a <- mutate(amzp, animalFood = ifelse(grepl(searchTerm, amzp$NozamaTitle, ignore.case = TRUE) == TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))
```

does actually work. Although it contains several components which are not needed (the `ifelse`-statement and using `data$column` inside a standard dplyr function), it gives the desired result:

```
> amzp.a
    ID NozamaItemID                                                     NozamaTitle animalFood
1 4557  12000017544  Starbucks Double Shot Espresso Light (4 Count, 6.5 Fl Oz Each)      FALSE
2 4558  12000021992                                         Pepsi, 8Ct, 12Oz Bottle      FALSE
3 4559  12000024542                      Zuke'S Natural Hip Action dog Treats, 3 Oz       TRUE
4 4560  12000030680                   Pepsi Made With Real Sugar, 12 Ct, 12 Oz Cans      FALSE
5 4561  12000030680                   Pepsi Made With Real Sugar, 12 Ct, 12 Oz Cans      FALSE
6 4562  12000030680                   Pepsi Made With Real Sugar, 12 Ct, 12 Oz Cans      FALSE
```

So, you might want to describe the *"does not work"* statement in more detail.

Comment: Thank you all! I guess I overlooked something as the solution indeed works. However, I learned a lot and so this writing was worth it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve but if your aim is just to be left with only rows where the word "dog" appears in the `NozamaTitle` column, you just need to use `dplyr::filter`. Using `chickwts` as an example in lieu of a minimal reproducible example:

```
levels(chickwts$feed)
# [1] "casein"    "horsebean" "linseed"   "meatmeal"  "soybean"  
# [6] "sunflower"

df <- filter(chickwts, grepl("bean", feed))
df
#    weight      feed
# 1     179 horsebean
# 2     160 horsebean
# 3     136 horsebean
# ...
# 11    243   soybean
# 12    230   soybean
# 13    248   soybean
# ...
```

Is this what you're after?